# React hooks - How to update and render elements properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I press delete button, it only deletes the last element every time, regardless to index.
How can I do this proper way? Without changing `<input defaultValue={name} />` to `<input value={name} />` in Child component?, I've done it with `<input defaultValue={name} />`, but how could I do this with `value` property to an input?

```
export const App = () => {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState([
    "First",
    "Second",
    "third",
    "fourth",
  ]);
  const onChange = (params) => {
    doing(params); // etc.
  };
  function onDelete(index: number) {
    const nameArr = [...names];
    nameArr.splice(index, 1);
    setNames(nameArr);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((name, index) => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={index}
          name={name}
          index={index}
          onChange={onChange}
          onDelete={handleDelete}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = React.memo(({ name, index, onChange, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        defaultValue={name}
        onChange={(event) => onChange(index, event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => onDelete(index)}>delete</button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: you are passing an undefined function `handleDelete` to the child component - the function you define is called `onDelete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code (`onDelete` and `handleDelete`) but this is not the main issue. Your problem is using `index` as your `key`. Since you are removing some elements attached to the state, React can't decide how to sort the array again, because `index` here is not trustable.

You should use some unique values for your keys, if there is not, you should create them somehow. In the below example I try to mix `index` with the value:

```
key={`${index}${name}`}
```

Also, do not use methods like [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) since they mutate the state. `splice` change elements in place, so mutation. I used [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but you can use any other method which doesn't mutate the state.

```js
function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState([
    "First",
    "Second",
    "third",
    "fourth"
  ]);

  function onDelete(index) {
    setNames((prev) => prev.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((name, index) => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={`${index}${name}`}
          name={name}
          index={index}
          onDelete={onDelete}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const ChildComponent = React.memo(({ name, index, onChange, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        defaultValue={name}
        onChange={(event) => onChange(index, event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => onDelete(index)}>delete</button>
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```